# Understand foreign function interface (FFI) and language binding

Tags: language-agnostic, programming-languages, binding, ffi

Mixing different programming languages has long been something I don't quite understand. According to [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_function_interface#Operation_of_an_FFI), a foreign function interface (or FFI) can be done in several ways:

> 1. Requiring that guest-language    functions which are to be   host-language callable be specified   or implemented in a particular way;  often using a compatibility library  of some sort.
> 2. Use of a tool to automatically "wrap"    guest-language functions with    appropriate glue code, which performs    any necessary translation.
> 3. Use of wrapper libraries
> 4. Restricting the set of host language   capabilities which can be used  cross-language. For example, C++  functions called from C may not (in  general) include reference   parameters or throw exceptions.

**My questions:**

1. What are the differences between the
   1st, 2nd and 3rd ways? It seems to
   me they are all to compile the code of
   the called language into some
   library with object files and header
   files, which are then called by the
   calling language.
2. [One source it links](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?ForeignFunctionInterface) says,
   implementing an FFI can be done in
   several ways:

   > - Requiring the called functions in the target language implement a
   >   specific    protocol.
   > - Implementing a wrapper library that  takes a given low-language
   >   function, and "wraps" it with code to do data  conversion to/from the
   >   high-level language conventions.
   > - Requiring functions declared native    to use a subset of high-level  functionality (which is compatible with the low-level  language).

   I was wondering if the first way in
   the linked source is the same as the
   first way in Wikipedia?

   What does the third way in this
   source mean? Does it corresponds to the 4th way in Wikipedia?
3. In  [the same source](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?ForeignFunctionInterface), when comparing the three ways it lists, it seems to say
   the job of filling the gap between
   the two languages is gradually
   shifted from the called language
   to the calling language. I was
   wondering how to understand that? Is this shifting also true for the four ways in Wikipedia?
4. Are [Language binding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_binding) and FFI
   equivalent concepts? How are they
   related and differ?

   > a binding from a programming language
   > to a library or OS service is an API
   > providing that service in the
   > language.
5. I was wondering which way in the quotation from Wikipedia or from the source each of  the following  examples belongs to?

   - [Common Object Request Broker Architecture (CORBA)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORBA)
   - Calling C in C++, by the extern "C"    declaration in C++ to
     disable name    mangling.
   - Calling C in Matlab, by [MATLAB Interface to Shared Libraries](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_external/f43202.html),     i.e., first compiling C code to   shared library via general C
     compiler    such as gcc, and then
     loading,    calling a function from
     and unloading    the shared library
     via Matlab    functions
     loadlibrary(), calllib()    and
     unloadlibrary().
   - Calling C in Matlab, by [Creating C/C++ Language MEX-Files](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_external/f7667.html)
   - Calling Matlab in C, by [mcc compiler](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/compiler/mcc.html)
   - Calling C++ in Java, by [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface), and Calling Java in C++, also by [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface)
   - Calling C/C++ in other languages, Using [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/)
   - Calling C in Python, by  [Ctypes    module](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBQQFjAA&url=http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html&rct=j&q=%20python%20Ctypes%20module&ei=CJ6NTa_JO6HD0QGMm5GzCw&usg=AFQjCNGFU4h9pH7gqGNesVBGbT-a_rhhTg&sig2=FhphdTx19dXmEVZAOAMhPA&cad=rja).
   - [Cython](http://cython.org/)
   - Calling R in Python, by [RPy](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/)
   - [Programming Language Bindings to OpenGL from various languages](http://www.opengl.org/resources/bindings/), such as Python, Fortran and Java
   - Bindings for a C library, such as    [Cairo](http://cairographics.org/bindings/), from various languages,
     such as C++, Python, Java, Common Lisp

Answer (score 32):

May be a specific example will help. Let us take the host language as Python and the guest language as C. This means that Python will be calling C functions.

1. The first option is to write the C library in a particular way. In the case of Python the standard way would be to have the C function written with a first parameter of `Py_Object *` among other conditions. For example ([from here](http://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html#a-simple-example)):

```c
static PyObject *
spam_system(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    const char *command;
    int sts;
    
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s", &command))
        return NULL;
    sts = system(command);
    return Py_BuildValue("i", sts);
}
```

is a C function callable from Python. For this to work the library has to be written with Python compatibility in mind.

2. If you want to use an already existing C library, you need another option. One is to have a tool that generates wraps for this existing library in a format suitable for consumption by the host language. Take [Swig](http://www.swig.org/) which can be used to tie many languages. Given an existing C library you can use swig to effectively generate C code that calls your existing library while conforming to Python conventions. See [the example](http://www.swig.org/tutorial.html) for building a Python module.
3. Another option to use an already existing C library is to call it from a Python library that effectively wraps the calls at run time, like [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html). While in option 2 compilation was necessary, it is not this time.

Another thing is that there are a lot of options (which do overlap) for calling functions in one language from another language. There are FFIs (equivalent to language bindings as far as I know) which usually refer to calling between multiple languages *in the same process* (as part of the same executable, so to speak), and there are interprocess communication means (local and network). Things like CORBA and Web Services (SOAP or REST) and and COM+ and remote procedure calls in general are of the second category and are not seen as FFI. In fact, they mostly don't prescribe any particular language to be used at either side of the communication. I would loosely put them as IPC (interprocess communication) options, though this is simplification in the case of network based APi like CORBA and SOAP.

Having a go at your list, I would venture the following opinions:

- Common Object Request Broker Architecture: **IPC, not FFI**
- Calling C in C++, by the `extern "C"` declaration in C++ to disable name mangling. ****
- Calling C in Matlab, by MATLAB Interface to Shared Libraries **Option 3 (ctypes-like)**
- Calling C in Matlab, by Creating C/C++ Language MEX-Files **Option 2 (swig-like)**
- Calling Matlab in C, by mcc compiler **Option 2 (swig-like)**
- Calling C++ in Java, by JNI, and Calling Java in C++ by JNI **Option 3 (ctypes-like)**
- Calling C/C++ in other languages, Using SWIG **Option 2 (swig)**
- Calling C in Python, by Ctypes **Option 3 (ctypes)**
- Cython **Option 2 (swig-like)**
- Calling R in Python, by RPy **Option 3 (ctypes-like) in part, and partly about data exchange (not FFI)**

The next two are not foreign function interfaces at all, as the term is used. FFI is about the interaction between two programming languages and should be capable of making any library (with suitable restrictions) from one language available to the other. A particular library being accessible from one language does not an FFI make.

- Programming Language Bindings to OpenGL from various languages
- Bindings for a C library from various languages

Comment: +1 nice answer. One note: "Calling C in MATLAB by creating MEX-files" is more like "Option 1", it is the equivalent of writing a Python extension using its C API. You create a regular shared library with a special gateway routine that receives `mxArray*` parameters. As for "calling MATLAB in C using mcc compiler", it is not really FFI since this is simply C code calling other C code (MCC compiler generates regular shared libraries).

Comment: Another option that wasn't mentioned is "calling MATLAB in C using MATLAB Engine", which is similar to ["Python embedding"](http://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html) to continue the analogy (same as calling Java in C using JNI interface)

Comment: Muhammad, thank you! It took me so long to come back and make sense out of most of your reply. My apology. "The next two are not foreign function interfaces at all, as the term is used.... A particular library being accessible from one language does not an FFI make". For example, if I am correct, OpenGL (or Cairo as linked in my post) is implemented in a C library, and how is its binding in another language (say Python) implemented? Also one of the three FFI ways which you listed at the beginning of your post?

Comment: Also "Calling C++ in Java, by JNI, and Calling Java in C++ by JNI Option 3 (ctypes-like)", it seems to me JNI is like option 1.